# Can I use my remote cloudant(nosqlDB) path for CDTDatastoreManager directory in IBM Bluemix SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am migrating my application backend from Parse.com to IBM bluemix. 
I do not want the CDTDatastore to take control of my persistent store(Core Data) which already exist.

[As per the Blue mix Documentation:](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CDTDatastore)

```
 NSError *outError = nil;
 NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSURL *documentsDir = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                               inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
 NSURL *storeURL = [documentsDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"cloudant-sync-datastore"];
 NSString *path = [storeURL path];
```

Can I make my "storeURL" to be my remote database URL(https://apikey:apipassword@username.cloudant.com/my_database) i.e Cloudant Database?
I must be in position to create,update,delete,documents in my remote database Directly with out using `CDTReplicatorFactory` and no offline storage.

Please let me know if further architectural design of my application is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pod you should be looking for.
https://cocoapods.org/?q=ObjectiveCloudant

Answer (score 1):

I think no. Please go through their IBM bluemix library. their policy is offline first.

May be create a rest interface with API keys and username given if you want to use core data as persistent store.